# Can we read/write MXD Document using GeoTools

Tags: mxd, geotools

Is it possible we can read/write mxd document only using geotools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No
http://osdir.com/ml/gis.geotools2.user/2006-02/msg00007.html